# How to put text on left and right side of UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uibutton

I am new to iOS development and I recently got stucked with a problem where I am not able to set text on both sides of a button. Also I wish to add multi-line text in a button (as shown below). I have gone through lot of answers but none of them satisfied my requirement.[image: Here is the demo image of my would be solution]

Any suggestion or help would greatly be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: Are you constrained on using a single button? You can use a view and an overlay button on it, also the image seems like a UITableViewCell, you can use didSelect delegate method.

Comment: @iOSDeveloper, yes I am using storyboard constraints but this is not a UITableviewCell. It's a Button inside a View. But thanks for your suggestion

Comment: What you're showing looks like a custom UI component with at least 3 text labels and an additional view for the left red edge. There is nothing in UIKit itself that does the same thing, you'll have to roll your own.

Comment: @Gereon, thanks, I think your idea of 3 text labels and an additional view may help me.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely go with a custom `UIButton` class. The reason for this is that `UIButton` has other properties that you will want, like being recognized by iOS as a *button*, conform to Accessibility as a *button*, show up in storyboard as a button class, let your co-workers see that it actually is a button, have same/similar interface as a button, and so on.

Creating a custom button isn't that hard. Basically, just sub-class `UIButton` and implement `awakeFromNib` to set up the internals and `layoutSubviews` to position and size everything.

Here is an outline of how to do it...

**1. Create a UIButton sub-class (.h)**
Add the custom interface to the **header** file. It could look something like this.

```
@interface MyButton : UIButton

- (void)setServiceText:(NSString *)serviceText;
- (void)setPriceText:(NSString *)priceText;
- (void)setTimeText:(NSString *)timeText;

@end
```

**2. Add controls to hold the internals of your button (.m)**
The three labels and a view to use as the red sidebar. From here on you add to the **code** file.

```
@interface MyButton ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *serviceLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *priceLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *timeLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *redSideBarView;

@end
```

**3. Add code corresponding to the interface (.m)**
Since `UILabel` redraws itself when we set the `text` property, we do not need to do more to make it appear on the button.

```
- (void)setServiceText:(NSString *)serviceText {
    _serviceLabel.text = serviceText;
}

- (void)setPriceText:(NSString *)priceText {
    _priceLabel.text = priceText;
}

- (void)setTimeText:(NSString *)timeText {
    _timeLabel.text = timeText;
}
```

**4. Implement awakeFromNib (.m)**
This method will be called when Storyboard instantiate your button, so here is a good place to create your labels and do other stuff that only needs to be done once.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    _sideBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    _sideBarView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self addSubview:_sideBarView];

    _serviceLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    _serviceLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0];
    [self addSubview:_serviceLabel];

    _priceLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    _priceLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    _priceLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
    _priceLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    [self addSubview:_priceLabel];

    _timeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    _timeLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
    [self addSubview:_timeLabel];

    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

**5. Add code to layout your button (.m)**
This is the final piece of the custom button code. Note that layoutSubviews will usually be called several times during the controls lifetime, so do not add sub-views here. Use it to position and size the internals of your button. `self.bounds.size` represents the current size of your button, so this is a good reference for all other elements.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    // Layout sub-elements
    CGFloat buttonWidth = self.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat buttonHeight = self.bounds.size.height;

    _serviceLabel.frame = CGRectMake(30.0, 2.0, buttonWidth * 0.7, buttonHeight * 0.5);
    _priceLabel.frame = CGRectMake(buttonWidth - 40, 5.0, 30.0, buttonHeight * 0.4);
    _timeLabel.frame = CGRectMake(30.0, buttonHeight * 0.5, buttonWidth * 0.7, buttonHeight * 0.4);
    _sideBarView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, buttonHeight);

    self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
}
```

**6. Use it!**
To use it you create a regular button in Storyboard, then in the Identity Inspector, select your new button class. As usual, tie the button to a variable in your **view controller class**. The variable should be of *your* button class, of course. That's it for the design!

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MyButton *button;
```

Now don't forget to set the properties.

```
self.button.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[self.button setServiceText:@"FULL SERVICE HAIRCUT"];
[self.button setPriceText:@"$30"];
[self.button setTimeText:@"30 minutes"];
```

A couple of things I didn't address here was the gradient and the drop shadow. The gradient is probably best done with a `CAGradientLayer` added to the button's view's layer. The drop shadow needs a bit more coding, since you are clipping the button to have rounded corners. Probably you need to add one more `UIView` in between to contain everything that you then clip, and then add shadow to the button view.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't go with a UIButton but with a UIView with Labels from Xib. Tutorial on that can be found here: [link](https://medium.com/@brianclouser/swift-3-creating-a-custom-view-from-a-xib-ecdfe5b3a960).

Then you may add a target to your UIView, so that when tapping it will call some method (as would UIButton do):

```
yourView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(buttonTapped))
yourView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

And method:

```
@objc func buttonTapped() {
    // do what you need on tap here
}
```

Hope it helps! Please comment if you have questions.

PS. I'm not sure but from what I see you are probably building a UITableView. is it? Can you please show a design of the full screen? If you have many "buttons" like that then it's not a single "button" but a Table View.

Answer (score 0):

To display multiple lines use below code

```
button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
button.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2; // or 0(Zero)
```

And you need to add UIView and add tap gesture to that view and design that view like above image.

For Gestures

```
//Create tap gustures for view
UITapGestureRecognizer *viewTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onClickView:)];
[self.yourViewName addGestureRecognizer: viewTap];

- (void) onClickView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
//Write your code
}
```

This is one approach.

And second one is...

For this use UITableViewCell and design that cell.

This is second approach.